# iOS Repeat Push Notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have an existing app that receives push notifications. I've been requested to implement a feature where the user must acknowledge the push notification. If the user does not acknowledge the notification, then they will be alerted again after a set time, until they finally do acknowledge it.

So far, the only solution I've come up with is:

We send a notification from our server to APNS. When the user opens the app after receiving a notification, the app will then send an acknowledgement back to the server. If the server does not receive an acknowledgement from the device within X minutes, it will automatically send another notification.

Is there a better way of implementing this kind of feature, where I'm not relying on sending acknowledgments back to the server?

Comment: You could send a silent push to the app and use that to trigger a repeating local notification. When the user opens the app cancel the local notification

Comment: I was looking into this - I thought that the app would only had 30 seconds to do what it needs to do before it is suspended again. This interval for the notifications is too small. Am I understanding silent notifcations correctly?

Comment: It only takes a fraction of a second to schedule a repeating notification. Once it is scheduled iOS takes care of delivering it.

Comment: After doing more research into silent push notifications it became clear that they won't be delivered if the app has been force killed by the user or hasn't been started after a phone restart, so this isn't a viable solution unfortunately. Thanks though!

Answer (score -2):

Create Accept/Reject actions for push notification and save that info on server, so that we can differentiate the accepted ones and others